# Why is UISearchController search bar incorrectly positioned?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a UITableViewController where I have placed a search bar in the `tableHeaderView`. It all looks fine like the picture below.
[image]

But, the problem is when it is presented:[image]

As you can see, it is mostly hidden above the top of the screen.

Here is the code I used to set it up in the tableview controller's viewDidLoad:

```
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Presets..."
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:0, y:searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height);
```

If I print the frame of the searchbar, it's origin is (0,0).
I have tried everything I can think of, but nothing works

Comment: Try setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` on your UIViewController. That should shift the subviews of your view controller's view to below the navigation bar.

Comment: try setting `searchController.definespresentationcontext` as `true`

Comment: Thanks, but neither of the above options helped...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if I check `Translucent` in the Navigation Bar's Attributes Inspector in IB the issue is resolved.

This leads me to believe that leaving that unchecked and setting `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to  `true` would also work, but I found this not to be the case.